# Does jqgrid cut off leading zeroes

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Does jqGrid cut off leading zeroes? I have some values coming from database which when displayed using jqgrid have their leading zeroes cut off.

Any suggestions regarding this?

Thanks.

Here is the column format I am using:

```
colModel:[
         {name:'id_no',index:'id_no', sorttype:"string"}
]
```

Comment: As far as I know it should not.  Perhaps it is your data.  Are you returning your data to your grid as JSON? In any event you need provide more detail.

Comment: How you define the column in the jqGrid which you describes? Do you use any formatter? You can display data as text, so no cutting of can took place.

Comment: @Oleg. Iam not using any formatter.I edited my question with the column format I am using                                             @John. I am using JSON format to return data to my grid. The data format in database is varchar, but some of the data has leading zeroes.

Comment: Have you used Firebug to inspect the JSON data being returned to your grid, to confirm that they are returned with leading zeros?

Comment: @Justin: the JSON data is returning without the zeroes.

Comment: There it is - you confirmed your problem is in your web service layer and not jqGrid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comments, your web service is truncating the zero's, not jqGrid.

To further isolate the problem I recommend you post some of your server-side code to retrieve data from the database and serialize it to JSON.

Comment: The returned JSON was truncating the zeroes. Got it solved by placing &nbsp;. Read some recommndations to add some string before the value, but adding &nbsp did the trick

Comment: It's always nice to know the root cause of a problem... anyway, I'm glad you fixed it :)